# Sample multivariate distribution sequentially: does this algorithm work and why?

Tags: simulation, multinomial-distribution

(To simplify the notation, I assume $dim=3$) Because for any multivariate distribution $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, we can write $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)=p(x_1)p(x_2|x_1)p(x_3|x_1,x_2)$. To draw a sample from it, can we do the following?

1. draw $x_1^*$ from $p(x_1)$
2. draw $x_2^*$ from $p(x_2|x_1^*)$
3. draw $x_3^*$ from $p(x_3|x_1^*,x_2^*)$

If this works, would someone explain the reason? If this does not work in general, will it work when $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is normal?

Comment: Your title appears to have an adverb followed by a word acting as a noun (*sequentially conditionals*). There may be an adjective missing in between or you may have intended to have an adjective instead of an adverb, Please clarify / fix the title

Comment: Yes, it works in general. To my way of thinking, it follows immediately from the definition of conditional distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works in general, for the reason you state:

$p(x_1,x_2,x_3)\,=\,p(x_1)\,p(x_2|x_1)\,p(x_3|x_1,x_2)$

Your first step samples from the first density on the RHS (that is, has the distribution of that marginal for $x_1$, your second samples from the second (conditional) density and your third step samples from the third. Then the triple thus generated has the distribution of the product on the right and consequently is a sample from the joint on the left.

(I suspect this is a duplicate but couldn't locate one in a reasonable time)